# How to get Response object in ContainerResponseFilter of Apache CXF3.0?

Tags: java, jax-rs, cxf

When I used Apache CXF2.0, I have a response handler likes that:

```
public class CustomResponseHandler implements ResponseHandler
{
    @Override
    public Response handleResponse(Message paramMessage, OperationResourceInfo paramOperationResourceInfo,
            Response paramResponse)
    {...}
}
```

Now, I migrate to Apache CXF3.0, I defined a class that implement ContainerResponseFilter to achieve the same function, like that:

```
public class CustomResponseHandler implements ContainerResponseFilter 
{
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException
    {...}
}
```

But now, I want to get Response object in the filter, how can I do? I didn't find any methods to get it, I want to change some properties of the Response, so I think I need to get it.

Comment: What properties did you want to change?